# Focus on next link when keyboard entered on Show more

Tags: angular, accessibility

I am working on accessibility and have a set of links with show more. If user presses enter on show more then I want the next link to be focused. Below is the code I am working on :

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let categoryItem of category.links; let j = index;">
            <li *ngIf="j <= 2">
                <a href="{{ categoryItem.url }}" target="_blank">{{ categoryItem.name }}</a>
            </li>

            <a *ngIf="j === 3 && category.links.length > 3" class="links-toggle" href="javascript:void(0);"
                (click)="toggle[i] = !toggle[i]" [attr.aria-expanded]="toggle[i]"
                [attr.aria-controls]="'show-more-links-panel-' + i" 
                attr.aria-label="Press space or enter to access more {{ category.title }} links">
                <i class="wdsk-icon wdsk-icon-toggle"></i>
                <a *ngIf="!toggle[i]" aria-label="Show More"
                    class="link-toggle-label">{{ 'USEFUL_LINKS.SHOW_MORE' | translate }}</a>
                <a *ngIf="toggle[i]" aria-label="Show Less"
                    class="link-toggle-label">{{ 'USEFUL_LINKS.SHOW_LESS' | translate }}</a>
            </a>

            <div *ngIf="category.links.length > 3" class="useful-links-show-more" [ngbCollapse]="!toggle[i]">
                <li *ngIf="j > 2">
                    <a tabindex="0" [attr.id]="'show-more-links-panel-' + i" href="{{ categoryItem.url }}"
                        target="_blank">{{ categoryItem.name }}</a>
                </li>
            </div>
        </ng-container>
```

Comment: Can be useful to understand better your problem if you reproduce it on https://stackblitz.com/

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell what your use case is, but moving a user's focus isn't something that should be done lightly as it may cause more confusion for users.

I would instead recommend keeping focus on the 'show more/show less' link and using the `aria-expanded` attribute to indicate to the user that content has been expanded/collapsed.